# wget images with certain path

Tags: sed, grep, filenames, wget

I am looking to only grab images from a document with a certain path; for example:

```
example.com/uploads/287167/file_name.jpg
```

and only grab those with the uploads/number/filename.

I am currently doing it this way:

```
wget http://example.com/news/36843 -q -O - | sed -n -e"s%^.*\(http://example.com/uploads/[0-9][^ \"\']*\.jpg\).*$%\1%p" | xargs wget -q
```

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: You could replace wget with curl, that's another way of doing it. Are you looking for a list of alternative operations? That could be quite long.

Comment: @chrismccoy Look at `-A/-R` options. They're `comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.`

Comment: can the -A allow for paths only uploads/ etc

Answer (score 2):

It would be a little easier to do this:

```
wget http://example.com/news/36843 -q -O - \
  | grep -Eo 'http://example.com/uploads/[0-9]+/[^"]+\.jpg' \
  | wget -i -
```

As to `-A`, you can filter jpg files. To filter the path you'd need `-I`. But it works in recursive mode only so it may download more than you want:

```
wget http://example.com/news/36843 -r --level 1 -A jpg -I "/uploads/[0-9]*"
```

Untested.